# Boolean response to CSV

Tags: java, split

Trying to write a method for a CSV that should return true if any value in the list is the String "surfing is fun", and false otherwise.

```
public boolean Practice.parseCSV(String s){
   string s1 = s.split(String ",") 
   for(int i=0; i < s1.length; i++){
      if(s1[i]== "surfing is fun")
         {return true;}
      else{
         return false;}

}
```

This is my rough idea. We have not gone over anything similar to this so I am kind of doing this from scratch. What do you think? I honestly am not at all familiar with regex

Comment: It'd be a good idea to add a language tag so it reaches an appropriate audience...

Comment: make sure you `trim()` the `String` before comparison.  There are lots of syntax errors if this is supposed to to Java - please try and post code that at least compiles...

Comment: try reading the java tutorial.  This is a classic mistake.  = compairs the memory location of a reverence.  something else (maybe the equals() method) compairs string values.

Comment: Have you learnt about regex?

Comment: I'm sure this is an exercise to learn more about iterations and/or string comparisons. So I don't think RegEx would consist of a valid answer..  I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not just post your CS homework to stack overflow.  That aside, I noticed a few problems with your code you may want to check.

> s.split(String ",")

You need to assign a variable name and type to this object.

> if("surfing is fun" = s[i])

This is not a comparison and will not return true or false.

> {parseCSV = true}

You cannot assign a value to an object that has not been defined. I suggest you so something like this:

> if (s[i] == "surfing is fun") return true
>   Then at the end of the loop return false, because presumably it would have already returned true and exited if the string contained "surfing is fun".

Answer (score 0):

First step is to analyze the requirements.

```
Return False: a,b,c,d
Return True: a,surfing is fun,
Return False: a,s8fing is fun,b
```

Now walk through in your head how you'd do this.
looks like you have a good idea of  how to do it above. You

1. Split the incoming string using ',' into an array or list.
2. Iterate that list and check it for the value you are looking for.

Note, you could probably kick out of the for loop once you found true.

Hope this helps